# ASP.NET MVC How to call a secured page from a windows app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC app that has forms authentication enabled.

The app allows printing of invoices.

I have an external app that converts html to pdf.

How can I call the secured page from this pdf converter app
so that some security remains?

The PDF converter app just requires a URL.

One thought was to create a HttpHandler for an extenion
of say .print and pass a public key in the URL qureystring
that can be validated by the MVC app.

Any ideas on this?

Malcolm

Comment: Having an HttpHandler or a controller for printing seems like a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a number of things to secure this.

1. Use OAuth to implement the security in the application. This allows the user of the invoicing app to authenticate when access the PDF app.
2. Implement OpenID, SAML or other single sign-on protocol to re-authenticate the user.
3. Implement a custom scheme: POST the key to access the PDF app, make sure to use SSL, use a nonce.

Options 1 and 2 are similar. Option 3 is fairly secure if implemented correctly. Most times you want to use a tried and tested solution as implementing these things with a good level of security can be tricky. There are libraries out there to help with options 1 and 2.

Query strings are easily exposed, do not pass keys on the query string as SSL will not protect them. If you implement your solution you should POST to the server and send the key in the body of the request. That way SSL can protect the key in transit. You should also use a nonce value to protect your PDF converter app.

Comment: @BrianLy: I think he already has authentication in place, and he's just trying to secure the invoice generation piece (which currently isn't publicly accessible).